# "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" when coding a Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to make a discord bot recently(using node), and I keep encountering into a "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined". I've tried changing the "toLowerCase" to "toUpperCase" but doesn't resolve the problem.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The bot is online!");
    client.user.setActivity('Servers', { type: 'WATCHING' });


}); 

const isCommand = (message, cmdName) => message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + cmdName);
const rollDice = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
client.on('message', function (message){
    if(message.author.bot) return;
     if(isCommand(message + "hello")) 
        message.reply(" Hi! I didn't want to make you feel lonely so I wanted to say hi.");
        if(isCommand(message , "rolldice")) {
            message.reply("You rolled a "+ rollDice());
   }




});
```

Comment: shouldn't this `if(isCommand(message + "hello"))`  be `if(isCommand(message ,"hello"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because  `message.content` is undefined, there is no property `toLowerCase` on `undefined`. You need to check what `message` contains and if it even has a `content` property in it.

And as @Aafaq said, it should be `if(isCommand(message ,"hello"))` otherwise you're just passing one parameter.

Even then, you need to `console.log` your message object in the callback and see what it's receiving and then access the proper property.

Comment: Error is because of this line `if(isCommand(message + "hello"))` as this will concat the "hello" string in the message object and message.content will become undefined even if the `message.content` is present.

Answer (score 0):

Everything above startcode is fine, It can be mended by :

```js
//startcode
client.on('message', function (message){
const isCommand = (message, cmdName) => message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + cmdName);
const rollDice = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(message.author.bot) return;
     if(isCommand(message + "hello")) 
        message.reply(" Hi! I didn't want to make you feel lonely so I wanted to say hi.");
        if(isCommand(message , "rolldice")) {
            message.reply("You rolled a "+ rollDice());
   }
```